# How can I express this VB code in C#?

Tags: c#, vbscript

How can I convert this from vb to c#?

```
 Call WshShell.Run( "API_CALLBACK.exe", 0, True )  
 WScript.Sleep(10000)  

 WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")  
 WScript.Sleep(3000)  
 WshShell.SendKeys("%S")  
 WScript.Sleep(3000)  
 WshShell.SendKeys("%Y")
```

Thx
It is process.start("API_CALLBACK");? how to do with .sendkey?

Comment: Get rid of the `Call` keyword, lowercase the `True` and add semicolons?  Looks like almost-c# to me.  All it is is a bunch of method calls.

Comment: Ahhh...that might complicate things just a little.  Would have been nice to have that stated in the question.

Comment: @Daniel: what is? WScript is a COM object if that's what you mean

Comment: Do you want to reference the same COM object, or do you want to use more 'native' .NET functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but here are the things you'll need:

One way to star a process in .NET is the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method.  You'll have to look for the overload the does what you need it to.

```
Process.Start("API_CALLBACK.exe");
```

There is also a handy [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class in the .NET framework.

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

And further, you can put the current thread to sleep with the [Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) method.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WshShell.Run("API_CALLBACK.exe", 0, true);
WScript.Sleep(10000);

WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
WScript.Sleep(3000);
WshShell.SendKeys("%S");
WScript.Sleep(3000);
WshShell.SendKeys("%Y");
```

Comment: This assumes that the OP wants to use the old COM libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sending Keystrokes to another Application in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx).